# Get simple data in xml attribute

Tags: php, xml

I want to get and echo the data in this simple XML format :

```
<top>
<file>
<my data="first"/>
</file>
<file>
<my data="second"/>
</file>
</top>
```

And i want to echo out with php this :

```
first,second
```

i need to give the path of XML file and get that results.

How to do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, you need to extract the values using `simplexml_load_string()` function, then you need to loop the values. Since, `first` and `second` are attributes, you also need to use also `attributes()`. Consider this example:

```
$raw_xml = '<top>
<file>
<my data="first"/>
</file>
<file>
<my data="second"/>
</file>
</top>';
$data = array();
$xml = simplexml_load_string($raw_xml);
foreach($xml->file as $key => $value) {
    $value = reset($value);
    $data[] = (string) $value->attributes()['data'];
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($data);
echo "</pre>";
```

Sample Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => first
    [1] => second
)
```

Edit: if you want to just echo try this.

```
echo implode(',', $data); // should output first,second
```

Comment: VERY thanks, if i want to give a XML file from url , what sould i do ? and if i want to echo out the `first` and `second` like : `first,second` what to do?  tnx.

Comment: @user3706471 if you want to just echo it, you can just implode the values. check the edit